# Plot graph with 4 equations consist of f(x,y, xy)

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I'd like to plot a graph which contains 4 functions as shown below:

```
 xy1: - 12.8 x - 0.108 y + xy >= -1.3824
 xy2: - 40 x - 5 y + xy >= -200
 xy3: - 40 x - 0.108 y + xy <= -4.32
 xy4: - 12.8 x - 5 y + xy <= -64
```

I started off by generating data for x and y

```
 import numpy as np
 x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
 y = np.linspace(0, 40, 100)
```

But then when I tried to plot the graph, I started to confuse about how should I reformulate the equations so that it is appropriate value for x, y, xy?

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.plot((-1.3824 + (12.8 * x) + (0.108 * y)), y)   <--- this doesn't seems to be right
 plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `contourf`:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

x, y = np.mgrid[-10:10:100j, -10:50:100j]
z1 = - 12.8 * x - 0.108 * y + x * y + 1.3824
z2 = - 40 * x - 5 * y + x * y + 200
z3 = - 40 * x - 0.108 * y + x * y + 4.32
z4 = - 12.8 * x - 5 * y + x * y + 64

fig, axes = pl.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 8))
axes = axes.ravel()
axes[0].contourf(x, y, z1, levels=[0, 1e10], alpha=0.2, colors=["blue"])
axes[1].contourf(x, y, z2, levels=[0, 1e10], alpha=0.2, colors=["green"])
axes[2].contourf(x, y, z3, levels=[-1e10, 0], alpha=0.2, colors=["red"])
axes[3].contourf(x, y, z4, levels=[-1e10, 0], alpha=0.2, colors=["yellow"])
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `contour` for implicit function plotting. By the way I don't think you can plot multiple functions with inequality on the same graph because you have to show the ranges in the 2D plane, and they overlap each other.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 40, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

XY1 = (-12.8*X - 0.108*Y + X*Y) >= -1.3824
XY2 = - 40*X - 5*Y + X*Y >= -200
XY3 = - 40*X - 0.108*y + X*Y <= -4.32
XY4 = - 12.8*X - 5*Y + X*Y <= -64

plt.contour(X,Y, XY1)
plt.contour(X,Y, XY2)
plt.contour(X,Y, XY3)
plt.contour(X,Y, XY4)
plt.show()
```

================================================================

UPDATE:

Seems like `sympy`'s `plot_implicit` works so much better. You may need to install it.

```
from sympy import plot_implicit, symbols, And
x, y = symbols('x y') 

p1 = plot_implicit(And(-12.8*x - 0.108*y + x*y >= -1.3824), (x,0,5), (y,0,40))
p2 = plot_implicit(And(-40*x - 5*y + x*y >= -200), (x,0,5), (y,0,40))
p3 = plot_implicit(And(-40*x - 0.108*y + x*y <= -4.32), (x,0,5), (y,0,40))
p4 = plot_implicit(And(-12.8*x - 5*y + x*y <= -64), (x,0,5), (y,0,40))
```

Results:

[image: p1][image: p2][image: p3][image: p4]